# Unable to set processor affinity after adding process to a job with specified group

Tags: c#, winapi, process, processor, affinity

I'm basically trying to start a new process with specified NUMA group and processor affinity.
I'm doing this in C#.
Setting `ProcessorAffinity` property of the process does not work for me because it only works for the first NUMA group.

I'm creating a job object, setting group for the job, then adding the process to the job.
This changes NUMA group for the process. However once I do that I'm not able to set processor affinity for the process.

The `SetProcessAffinityMask` returns true but `GetProcessAffinityMask` returns same value as before.

Setting affinity mask before the process is added to the job works, but the affinity gets once process is added to the job.

My testing code (below) writes following to the console:

- Calling SetProcessAffinityMask to 1
- GetProcessAffinityMask now returns 1
- Setting job group to 0
- Adding process to the job.
- GetProcessAffinityMask now returns 15
- Calling again SetProcessAffinityMask to 1
- GetProcessAffinityMask now returns 15

I would expect the last value returned by `GetProcessAffinityMask` to be 1 or not be changed to 15 at all when process is added to the job.

Any help would be appreciated.

```
using System;
using System.Diagnostics;
using System.Runtime.InteropServices;
namespace ChangeGroupUsingJob
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            // start the process
            var process = new Process
            {
                StartInfo = new ProcessStartInfo
                {
                    FileName = "notepad.exe"
                }
            };

            process.Start();

            UIntPtr targetAffinityMask = new UIntPtr(1);

            Console.WriteLine("Calling SetProcessAffinityMask to " + targetAffinityMask);

            if (!SetProcessAffinityMask(process.Handle, targetAffinityMask))
                Console.WriteLine("Error code: " + Marshal.GetLastWin32Error());

            ReportProcessAffinityMask(process);

            // create job
            var jobObjectHandle = CreateJobObject(IntPtr.Zero, null);

            ushort group = 0;
            int length = Marshal.SizeOf(typeof(ushort));
            IntPtr groupInfoPtr = Marshal.AllocHGlobal(length);
            Marshal.StructureToPtr(group, groupInfoPtr, false);

            Console.WriteLine("Setting job group to " + group);

            // set job info
            var jobInfoSet = SetInformationJobObject(jobObjectHandle, JobObjectInfoType.GroupInformation, groupInfoPtr, (uint)length);

            Console.WriteLine("Adding process to the job.");

            // assign process to the job
            var processAddedToJob = AssignProcessToJobObject(jobObjectHandle, process.Handle);

            ReportProcessAffinityMask(process);

            Console.WriteLine("Calling again SetProcessAffinityMask to " + targetAffinityMask);

            if (!SetProcessAffinityMask(process.Handle, targetAffinityMask))
                Console.WriteLine("Error code: " + Marshal.GetLastWin32Error());

            ReportProcessAffinityMask(process);

            // close the job (process should still keep running)
            var handleClosed = CloseHandle(jobObjectHandle);

            Console.ReadLine();
        }

        private static void ReportProcessAffinityMask(Process process)
        {
            UIntPtr processAffinityMask;
            UIntPtr systemAffinityMask;
            bool getProcessAffinityMaskSuccess;
            getProcessAffinityMaskSuccess = GetProcessAffinityMask(process.Handle, out processAffinityMask, out systemAffinityMask);
            Console.WriteLine("GetProcessAffinityMask now returns " + processAffinityMask);
        }

        [DllImport(dllName: "kernel32.dll", CharSet = CharSet.Unicode, SetLastError = true)]
        static extern IntPtr CreateJobObject(IntPtr securityAttributes, string name);

        [DllImport(dllName: "kernel32.dll", SetLastError = true)]
        static extern bool CloseHandle(IntPtr handle);

        [DllImport("kernel32.dll")]
        static extern bool SetInformationJobObject(IntPtr hJob, JobObjectInfoType infoType, IntPtr lpJobObjectInfo, UInt32 cbJobObjectInfoLength);

        [DllImport("kernel32.dll", SetLastError = true)]
        static extern bool AssignProcessToJobObject(IntPtr job, IntPtr process);

        [DllImport("kernel32.dll", SetLastError = true)]
        static extern bool SetProcessAffinityMask(IntPtr process, UIntPtr processAffinityMask);

        [DllImport("kernel32.dll", SetLastError = true)]
        static extern bool GetProcessAffinityMask(IntPtr hProcess, out UIntPtr lpProcessAffinityMask, out UIntPtr lpSystemAffinityMask);

        public enum JobObjectInfoType
        {
            AssociateCompletionPortInformation = 7,
            BasicLimitInformation = 2,
            BasicUIRestrictions = 4,
            EndOfJobTimeInformation = 6,
            ExtendedLimitInformation = 9,
            SecurityLimitInformation = 5,
            GroupInformation = 11
        }
    }
}
```